# Avoid adding png images to git

Tags: git, image

In my project i am doing snapshot testing. The snapshot testing creates visual png images to be compared with for later use.

I need to find a way to "keep" those images, and be able to compare them in future uses, but not commit them into git.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, these images will only change if your UI changes visually. So they are part of your test suite. Then why not commit them? If this makes the repo too big, you could look into Git LFS.

Comment: A *".gitignore"* file maybe?

Comment: i need the files to BE there, for anyone else who checks out the project

Answer (score 1):

Use [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) which stores the history of the files, but the content is stored in the cloud. This avoids bloating out the repository size while allowing you to track large files.